# Subscribing to the wrong topic

Tags: c++, ros

My problem is that I want to subscribe to the Topic "joy" but from a class.

Let's say that i have a class named My_Class.

As protected method i wrote the subscriber.

```
protected:
   
 ros::Subscriber my_subscriber;
```

Then i iniatlized it.

```
my_subscriber = nh_.subscribe("joy", 1, &My_Class::my_subscriber_cb, this);
```

Then i wrote my Callback Function

```
void my_subscriber_cb(const sensor_msgs::Joy::ConstPtr& msg){}
```

Then i initialised my node like this:

```cpp
    // ROS-Node Initialisation
    ros::init(argc, argv, "TEST_CORE", ros::init_options::NoSigintHandler);
```

The problem is that at the end when i show the topic with **rostopic list**

I get a topic named `TEST_CORE/joy`. So I'm subscribing to `TEST_CORE/joy` and not to `/joy` .

What can i do or change to get the Data of my gamepad from the right Topic ?

Comment: how are you running your node? using `rosrun` directly or using a launch file?

Comment: Hello I'm using rosrun directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the documentation at [ROS Wiki: Names](http://wiki.ros.org/Names). Names are generally relative, this means they are created based on the node name. Since your node name is `TEST_CORE`, the result of a subscription to `joy` is `TEST_CORE/joy`. To subscribe to a absolute topic, you need to add `/` in front of the topic. So

```
my_subscriber = nh_.subscribe("/joy", 1, &My_Class::my_subscriber_cb, this);
```

allows the subsctiption which is required by you.

Comment: I agree that this should fix the issue. This doesn't fully explain what he is seeing though. According to the Names document a node `/node1` should map `bar` into `/bar` and if Slachcrash is running rosrun directly then there shouldn't be a namespace. So where is the namespace 'TEST_CORE' coming from?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The documentation says: ```By default, resolution is done relative to the node's namespace. For example, the node /wg/node1 has the namespace /wg, so the name node2 will resolve to /wg/node2.``` isnt it?

Comment: exactly, but his node doesn't seem to have a namespace, so the first row in the table in Section 1.1.2 should apply. I suspect though that his problem description is somehow incomplete and he *is* starting it in a namespace after all.

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you for your help. This fixed my issue. My answer about rosrun is wrong. I thought you were talking about the joy_node. TEST_CORE is a namespace. With the documentation of Names it all makes sense now.